# LWUIT application not display in the full screen mode in the LG devices Navigation Bar is displayed at bottom

Tags: java-me, lwuit

[image]In LWUIT application how to display LWUIT Forms in the Full Screen Mode.currently in LG Devices form is not displaying in the Full Screen Mode.at bottom of the Screen it Navigation bar is display with Num and Ok command at Left and right and Simple Navigation image at center part of the bottom area.
i want to remove this bar from my application.
i want to display Form in the Full Screen.also attach screen shot for the same.

Comment: is it compulsory to use only LG Devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi thanks shai for your answer here is the answer i get from the LG official developer forum.Unfortunately, you can not use LGE-MIDlet-Display-Nav-Keypad attribute. LG proprietary JAD attributes are only for devices that support LGJP. KM900 and KP501 do not support LGJP. And T300 suports LGJP1. Although T300 supports LGJP1, LGE-MIDlet-Display-Nav-Keypad is an optional attribute in LGJP1 (it's mandatory from LGJP2).
i am able to remove the information bar using LGE-MIDlet-Indicator : HIDE on the LG Lollipop device.so on LG arana LGJP is not supported this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try `LGE-MIDlet-Display-Nav-Keypad: no` they "invented" that at some point and didn't bother notifying anyone ;-)

Comment: thanks Shai for you answer  after i add this then also Nav-Keypad is display on the Screen.

Comment: Are you sure? Try it both in the jad and manifest and if it still doesn't work please contact LG.

Comment: ya i try it both in jad and manifest but it does not work. Then i get that it is supported after the device which has a software version  LGJP version 2.0.